# Can I use a single "pthread_mutexattr_t" attribute to initialize two different mutexes?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, x86-64, suse

I am using **two mutexes** in my C program, I want both of them to be of type:

`PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK`

Other properties of both mutexes to be set as default.

Can I use a single `pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttrib;` with its "type" property set as above, to initialize both the mutexes? Is it safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

The `pthread_mutexattr_t` attribute is only used at mutex creation time, and is not modified by `pthread_mutex_init()`, nor is it needed after initialization (ie. you can also `pthread_mutexattr_destroy()` it later)

Comment: Thanks!! Also I saw [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html) that the pointer is passed to `const pthread_mutexattr_t`, so it cannot be changed by `pthread_mutex_init()`. Initially I didn't noticed that **const**.